# Mongodb autoConnectRetry option in connection string is not working with C# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, connection-string, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a quick questions here. I am using mongodb with C# and Java. Connectionstring that i use is:

```
mongodb.domain.com/?autoConnectRetry=true
```

The same connection string is working with Java but not with C#. I saw many posts around this that, if we remove autoConnectRetry option it works fine.

Looked at the logs and saw that its erroring out with below exception

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid option 'autoConnectRetry'.
Parameter name: url
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder.Parse(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl..ctor(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl.Create(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Create(String connectionString)
```

Is there any alternative that can make this work?

I am using .NET Framework 3.5 and Mongodb C# driver v 1.0

Answer (score 1):

There is just no such option ("autoConnectRetry") in C# MongoDb driver, while there is in Java, so you will have to implement retry logic yourself. If you just want to use the same connection string for both and don't care about retry logic - I think that in current version of the driver it no longer throws InvalidOperationException on unknown options.